# How to assign current date to row in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have the following private method in my form :

```
    function _verifywebsite ($id) {
    $row = $this->websites->fetchRow("id=$id");
    $row->verified_date = $this->_get_date(); // this is the line in question
    $row->save();
}
```

I assume that $row requires me to enter date as string value in correct date format.

But what if I want to include some SQL function, like NOW(), can I assign it to 
$row->verified_date somehow or it's against best practices?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code is enabling SQL expression for Active Record field:

`$row->verified_date = new Zend_Db_Expr('now()');`

As ZF Manual says:

> You might need values in the data
>   array to be treated as SQL 
>   expressions, in which case they should
>   not be quoted. By default, all data
>   values passed as strings are treated
>   as string literals. To specify that
>   the value is an SQL  expression and
>   therefore should not be quoted, pass
>   the value in the data array as an
>   object of type Zend_Db_Expr instead of
>   a plain string.